# Can't get Zeroconf to work

Tags: ubuntu, bonjour, zeroconf

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

I have two Ubuntu 10.04 boxes, "scout.local" and "jones.local"; they're both running the avahi daemon and they can both resolve their own Zeroconf hostnames, but not the other's.

On the same network there are two Macs that have no trouble pinging each other's Zeroconf ("Bonjour") hostnames.

Comment: Something about the way you wrote your question makes me wonder if you typed in the ".local" yourself when naming the machines, rather than letting Avahi add that itself when it advertises the machine on the network. So maybe you're actually advertisting "scout.local.local" and "jones.local.local".